# Using button_to to create new record in database, error: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, parameters

I am trying to create a very basic button_to that will create a new record in the database. At the moment, I am hard coding in the 'video_id'. However, I am getting the following error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: track

Request

Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"e60ap2UFOpyfCLPrqRpvYCyZrfQwZ8DtmBglYu4n",
 "video_id"=>"1"}
```

My create method in my 'Tracks' controller looks like this:

```
def create
   Track.create(track_params)
   redirect_to root_path
end

def track_params
   params.require(:track).permit(:video_id)
end
```

My button_to in my application.html.erb looks like this

```
<%= button_to 'Save track', {:controller => "tracks", :action => "create", :video_id => "1" } , :method=>:post %>
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated as I've been banging my head trying to solve this error for quite a while. To put things in context, what I ultimately want to achieve is the following solution: User searches for a keyphrase (a music video), which queries the Youtube API and displays the top 3 results. The user can then click the 'Save track' button to save the video_id of one of the three youtube videos to the track database. I've got up to the point where I can display the videos and now I'm trying to add this button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in `<%= button_to 'Save track', {:controller => "tracks", :action => "create", :video_id => "1" } , :method=>:post %>`

this is not good way to build form ([`button_to generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options.`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to))

if you still want use `button_to` helper try pass simple path with params:

```
<%= button_to 'Save track', "/tracks/create?video_id=5"  , :method=>:post %>
                           ^^^^^^^^^|^^^^^^|^^^^^^^^^^
                          controller|action|params
```

this should generates html like this:

```
<form action="/tracks/create?video_id=5" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save track">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="dUZL6a3NmlEZK9aVPEKX4rTxj/dTH2ZeBw1vCybWI8w=">
  </div>
</form>
```

Permit params:

```
def create
   Track.create(params.permit(:video_id))
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

Rails way for your case it is use `_path` helper and `link_to` helper.

Happy hacking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After following your solution, I also just needed to add this to my routes.rb file in order to get it to work: post "/tracks/create" => "tracks#create"

Answer (score 0):

The method:

`def track_params
   params.require(:track).permit(:video_id)
end`

means that you want a hash of particular parameters. In that hash (in `params`) you want a key `track` and assigned a value, which is also a hash with key `video_id` and an integer value. So your params should look like this:

`params = {track: { video_id: 1} }`

(Just wrapping `video_id` with `track`)

Try to change the button code like this:

`<%= button_to 'Save track', {:controller => "tracks", :action => "create", :track => {:video_id => "1"} } , :method=>:post %>`

I hope that helps.

Btw.: `track_params` method should be private.

Comment: `<%= button_to 'Save track', {:controller => "tracks", :action => "create", :track => {:video_id => "1"} } , :method=>:post %>` generate this path `/?track%5Bvideo_id%5D=1` so this can't be right answer.

Comment: i know how it works(path building) and yes i tested it.